# Insert html based on contain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, insert, contain

In this situation, I have one page, which will load with all different kinds of content (example: 5 different clothing catalogs).

I'm looking for a way to insert html based on specific text in a header.
I know this isn't right, but this may give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
$jq(document).ready(function(){
  $jq("h3:contains('Men')").insertBefore("<img src='images/men.png'>");
});
```

The end result I'm going for is being able to load different images on the same page depending on the specific text of the header.

Thank you!!!

Comment: What's wrong what you currently have?

Comment: It just isn't working.
The page will load fine, but when the content in question is present, the H3 won't load.

Comment: is there anyway we can take a look at the `html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `append` the img based on the `contains` criteria:

```
$("h3:contains('Men')").append("<img src='images/men.png'>");
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rakkq276/)

Comment: Or you can use `prepend()` if you want the image get "inserted" before the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
$jq(document).ready(function(){
  if($jq('h3').text() == "Men")
    $jq('h3').insertBefore("<img src='images/men.png'>");
});
```